# Usage figuratif de « sexy » (conveying "sexy applications")

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, usage, anglicismes

Passage tiré d'un livre de Physique :

> As such, the focus is on developing (fairly) precise definitions of
>   the key concepts used in the field, as well as on pointing out common
>   misconceptions, so as to make the subject easier to understand. We
>   thus leave the splashy color graphics—together with a description of
>   the latest **“sexy” applications**—to your primary textbook, and
>   instead concentrate here on a clear presentation of the core ideas.

Traduction

> En tant que tel, l’accent est mis sur l’élaboration de définitions
>   (assez) précises des concepts clés utilisés sur ce domaine, ainsi que
>   sur le signalement des idées fausses courantes, afin de rendre le
>   sujet plus facile à comprendre. Nous laissons donc les graphiques
>   colorés éclatants (accompagnés d'une description des dernières
>   **applications « sexy »**) à votre manuel principal. Au lieu de cela, nous
>   nous concentrons ici sur une présentation claire des idées de base.

En France un tel emploi figuratif du mot *sexy* sera-t-il choquant ? Dans un tel cas, avec quelle expression peut-on rendre la même idée ?

Comment: Je l'emploie régulièrement. Certains interlocuteurs ont un petit rictus, d'autres pas, mais tous comprennent ce que je veux dire et n'y voient pas de connotation sexuelle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J'ai une opinion différente sur cet emploi. Dans une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/33782) on présente *à succès* que je trouve utile. L'emploi de *sexy* n'est pas du tout choquant. D'autre part je le trouve tout simplement peu adapté ici, et son emploi en contexte constitue à mon avis une [extension de sens](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sexy) inutile adossée à une connaissance plus intime du [terme](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=sexy&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) en langue anglaise, voire sur un calque, ou autrement sur un changement de registre qui n'a pas sa place dans le genre d’œuvre présenté en question. D'ailleurs même en langue anglaise on a utilisé les guillemets, faisant par le fait même avec la langue ce qu'on affirme ne pas vouloir faire avec les applications dont on traite. Dire familièrement d'une application en physique (ou d'une *section chiffrée*, ou d'un *argument*, comme au Wiktionnaire) qu'elle est indirectement attrayante par extension (ou est-ce par insinuation au final) de la notion d'un «  charme attirant et aguichant, [...] du sex-appeal » ([Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/sexy/72492?q=sexy#71683)), je trouve ça vraiment nul et franchement de mauvais goût. Si on veut simplement dire *attrayant* qu'on le dise ou qu'on déballe une proposition : des applications *que tout le monde veut voir/dont tous veulent entendre parler/que tous veulent essayer* etc. En langue anglaise [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sexy#Synonyms) propose des synonymes comme *gorgeous, tasty, hot*. [Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/sexy/610956) traduit le terme au figuré par *sympa* ; on connaît de plus déjà le mot [*cool*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cool) si on veut faire dans ce registre-là, mais pourquoi donc, les sciences c'est *cool* sans avoir besoin de changer de registre. On pourrait utiliser [*à la page*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/page/57231/locution)/[mode](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/mode/51911/locution?q=%C3%A0%20la%20mode#181884), *populaires, au goût du jour, en vogue*... et on pourra par le fait même se passer des guillemets...

Answer (score 0):

Il n'y a rien de choquant dans ce néologisme en puissance ; la sexualité n'est pas en elle-même une chose vulgaire ; cependant le rapport de celle-ci avec les choses de la physique n'est que de très mauvais gout, que ce soit en anglais ou en français, à mon avis.

Termes possibles : des dernières applications brillantes, des dernières applications à succès, des dernières merveilles en faits d'application,…(bien sûr, il n'y a rien de figuratif dans ces expressions et je ne crois pas qu'il faille absolument insister sur l'utilisation d'un terme figuratif, mais on peut possiblement en trouver un, ce que je n'ai pas le moyen de faire pour l'instant.)

À tout hasard, je soumet la possibilité « dernières coquettes applications », dans lequel sont absentes les connotations charnelles que l'on trouve dans « sexy », mais il ne m'enthousiasme pas vraiment.